# How to build a multilingual Drupal site?

Tags: drupal, internationalization, drupal-views, multilingual, cck

I'd like to build a Drupal site with multiple languages. What modules will I be needing and how would I go about designing my content types, views and menus so that everytime these appear in the correct language?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901688/possible-pitfalls-on-a-multilingual-drupal-site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a huge question and needs too much to be answered here. To get you started, check out the core Locale module along with the [i18n module](http://drupal.org/project/i18n), and also see the [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/133977) for that module.

You'll find more help here if you post specific questions as you go along.